# Lazy Questions Are Destroying Your Site

Tags: discussion, quality-control, curation

When I visit the front page of this site, more often than not all I see is lazy questions, drowning out anything that's even slightly useful or interesting. Sometimes ignored, but more and more often I'm finding them upvoted, answered and actively engaged with, which is only going to encourage more such questions in the future.

I'm not talking about questions from beginners or laymen who don't have a deep knowledge of their religion. I'm not talking about questions from users who obviously don't speak English as a first language.

I'm talking about lazy questions, questions from users that show little to no effort to actually understanding what they're asking about. Users who don't even put in the effort to ask a clear coherent question in English, where they can't even be bothered to write in full sentences, much less use a proper title or select proper tags. Users who can't even be bothered to stay focused, or to respond to feedback, or to do much of anything except demand answers. Users who want someone else to post an answer that does all the effort of thinking for them, so they don't have to do any for themselves.

Regardless of ones expertise in the topic — or even the language — writing a clear and coherent question just involves putting the time and effort into actually *writing* one. And no matter how much or how little one knows about the topic, showing ones own research effort is not difficult, it simply requires actually *making* a research effort in the first place. Asking a good question isn't easy, but expecting anyone who actually *cares* about learning the answer to put the extra effort into a clear focused question that *gives* them that answer is hardly unreasonable.

Users who don't even care about the topic enough to actually work for the answers to their own questions, those are the types of users that can destroy this site if left unchecked: They do not contribute anything useful, all they do is take time, energy and resources away from the users who actually volunteer their expertise toward making Islam Stack Exchange a comprehensive repository of Islamic knowledge. By encouraging lazy questions, you're destroying the one thing that makes a Stack Exchange site worth visiting.

We'll never be able to provide high-quality individualized answers to everything that gets posted here, that simply doesn't scale: There will always be more people asking for help than there will be people who are both willing *and* able to provide that help. We cannot expect the users who actually *answer* the questions to do all the heavy lifting, not if we want to have a site where those users actually *want* to keep answering questions.

Community curation isn't simply a good idea, it's *crucial* to defining the direction of the site: Tolerating and encouraging lazy questions just means you get a site populated by lazy users who then end up posting lazy answers. This helps nobody.

Comment: 100% agreed. I've looked towards other stack exchange sites regarding the other religions and none of them are as bad as Islam Stack Exchange. Downvoted upon downvoted questions clog the list of questions and they hardly have any effort put into them. Hardly any other sites have such poorly written questions clogging their feed as much as this stack exchange does. Most of them here I've noticed have frequent panic-related questions over something they've written with a panicked mindset. It's really becoming an issue that needs to be resolved.