# Curation is a community effort: Is this really a site you can be proud of?

Tags: discussion, moderation, curation

This has been brought up countless times in the past, most recently with [Lazy Questions Are Destroying Your Site](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3543/22)

Yet instead of becoming a repository of useful Islamic knowledge to future visitors, we're increasingly plagued by lazy questions that have been asked hundreds of times before and are still only useful to one person at best.

**Islam.SE is almost ten years old. It is now a graduated site.** But can you honestly look at this site and be proud of it? Do you see a useful repository of Islamic knowledge, one which will stand the test of time and provide value for years to come? Does this site make the Internet a better place?

Or do you see a site bogged down in useless questions and uninformed opinions that is barely differentiable from any other Islamic forum out there?

This is a community site, which means that the *community* is responsible for keeping it clean, keeping it up-to-date, and keeping it *useful*. Moderators are volunteers who are expected to handle the situations that the community cannot. They are not, nor should they be, responsible for hand-holding the community and doing all the work of keeping this site clean because nobody else can be bothered to.

Every month we get **hundreds of new users** all of which come here looking for knowledge and expertise on the topic of Islam. In Ramadan alone we get **literally millions of views**, all of which come here looking for knowledge and expertise on the topic of Islam. We also get **hundreds of new posts**, and it is not reasonable to expect a small handful of moderators and dedicated users to do all the heavy lifting of keeping everything under control, to make visiting this site an experience worth repeating.

We have **thousands of active users** who have basic voting privileges to downvote bad questions, yet the worst questions on the front page have maybe one or two downvotes at best. We have thousands of users who can discuss and set policy on meta, yet it's always the same handful of names who even care enough to participate. We have thousands of users who can suggest edits, yet the front page is plagued by unfocused questions with the most basic of grammar errors.

I want to say this again, to make this perfectly clear because I think it has not yet sunk in for a lot of people: **IT IS NOT THE MODERATOR'S JOB TO CURATE THIS SITE. IT IS THE RESPONSIBILITY OF THE COMMUNITY.**

StackExchange provides valuable tools in the form of [Islam Meta](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com) and [Islam Chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=islam.stackexchange.com) for communicating with the community, to discuss policy, to discuss issues, or just to hang out and *be* a community. Both of those are practically a wasteland. In the last ten years, I can't recall the community bothering to develop a single new policy without a moderator needing to implement it first. This is not how StackExchange is supposed to work: **We the moderators are supposed to *enforce* community norms, not set them.**

We started this site because there's already countless Internet fora out there bogged down in low-quality questions, opinions, speculation and argument that only make it harder to find actual useful fact-based information. Forums which let themselves get derailed by patting each other on the back with peer support rather than spreading knowledge of the deen. Forums which push misinformation and contradictory opinions as if they're unassailable fact, which only confuses the people who need actual answers. **We need to be better than that.**

The *only* reason this site has survived as long as it has is because the moderator team and a *very* small handful of dedicated users has been actively working above and beyond our responsibilities simply to maintain the status quo, to ensure the  most basic level of quality: This is time and energy that keeps us afloat but which can no longer be spent providing expert answers or actually *improving* the site.

If the community as a whole can't be bothered to control the quality of the site, to determine what is or is not considered on-topic, to determine what is or is not considered an obstacle against the site's goal to create a **useful, valuable, repository of knowledge** on the topic of Islam, then **this site will be shut down**. If you don't care about your site, why should anyone else?

You all have the tools to make this either the best resource of Islamic knowledge on the Internet, or the worst. **USE THEM, USE THEM OFTEN, AND USE THEM WISELY**.

Make this a site you *can* be proud of.

Comment: JazakAllah alkhairen for this post. I'm trying to be more active on this site, inshaAllah that will help even just a little bit.

Comment: This site is a big challenge; I truly admire your patience.  I cannot mentally handle the things I've seen written about Jews, gays, rape, pedophilia, masturbation, sects, the OP's secretions, etc.  Maybe it's worthwhile thinking about cutting the Gordian knot, and doing something along the lines of [Medical Sciences](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/): drawing a hard line "personal Islamic advice" => "off-topic".

Comment: @RebeccaJ.Stones Hard line or no, it would still need significant community involvement to actually enforce anything. There's just far too many posts now for the moderator team to effectively police everything by themselves.

Answer (score 3):

Y'know, I was a bit surprised when the site graduated;  I'm even more surprised Stack Exchange announced they are going to the trouble of creating a design for the site.  ***Have Stack Exchange staff even looked at the site recently?***  I don't understand why they are willing to accept being affiliated with the content here.

- There are many questions which just make me feel disgusted in one way or another:
  [Touching Non Mehram](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/76229/17163)
  [Can parents marry off their adult son without his consent?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/76209/17163)
  [Apostasy and heterosexual and homosexual porn addiction](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/76061/17163)
  [I've committed zina and feel guilty. How do I tell my wife for forgiveness and then do tauba?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/75807/17163)
  [I had Wet dreams](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/75770/17163)

  More than anything else, these are the kinds of questions that make me avoid the site.  The ones that you feel fairly sure a crime has been committed.  The ultra-specific masturbation stories that make you feel nauseated.
- There are many questions which are ultra-personalized (they're more about the OP than Islam):
  [Timings for Tahajjud Prayer](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/76257/17163)
  [Creation of Allah (i.e. Aliens) creating us](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/76248/17163)
  [Can I be in my room alone with my cousin female me male?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/76242/17163)
  [Praying in vehicle](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/76231/17163)
  [Seperating & divorce due to financial crisis](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/76223/17163)
  [Questions about Jinn/Evil Eye](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/76220/17163)
  [Is there any body who sees light surrounding him like noor?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/76188/17163)
  [Is my job halal or haram](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/76176/17163)
- No-effort-shown fatwa requests:
  [Developing Remote administration tools and selling them](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/76245/17163)
  [Can both male and female have their nikkah without their parents knowing but later informing everyone and have a wedding?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/76185/17163)
  [Developing websites that sells game topups (points, credits etc)](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/76183/17163)
  [is it prohibited to sit immediately upon someone's left place](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/76180/17163)

Where are all the questions which ask for interpretations of Qur'an verses and hadith?

**If Islam.SE were a question, I'd vote to put it "on hold", until it has been improved**: it'd go through the close-edit-reopen cycle.

I estimate 80%+ of the recent questions posted here should be closed; there's so little about Islam.  If questions started off as closed, and users voted to open them, it'd likely be an improvement to the site.  I'm not going to vote to close (+edit) so many questions---I just don't have the energy (I've tried in the past, but there's just too much legwork left to too few people).  And I'm guessing if goldPseudo diamondly closes them, he'd get abused (more).

I feel this site needs more help than users realizing they have access to curation tools.  Maybe it's time to reach out to Stack Exchange for some guidance.

Perhaps we should also consider:

- Dropping the close threshold to 3 votes.
- Revising the custom close vote reasons to make them easier to use, and broader (I recall mentioning this years ago [Replacing the off-topic close reasons? (draft)](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3044/replacing-the-off-topic-close-reasons-draft;) I get that it's not an easy thing to change, though).