# Edits are not being checked

Tags: support, editing

***Update: They are reviewed but I
want to know  the cause
of this delay .***

My edits are not being approved or disapproved. *It has been 2-3 days, none of my edits are responded to.*

[image]

**Please approve or disapprove my edits and do tell the reason for this lazy behavior.**

Comment: 1) It is always better to put a link to the post. I had to search for this question, but there was not edit from you. 2) All your edits have been approved. I don't see any pending edit requests.

Comment: @Farhan, yes they were reviewed by mod (medisaif), this question is still up because I didn't get the reason for this much delay.

Comment: @Farhan I wasn't linking the question, I was trying to show that I am unable to edit a question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wish I had a better answer for you, but the fact is that everybody on this site is a volunteer, and a majority of the users [just don't care enough about curation](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3589/22) to spend even a couple minutes reviewing edits<sup>*1</sup>.

There are a handful of regulars who will go through the queues to approve edits, but as I said it's all volunteer work so they're just going to do it when they have time. And since suggested edits require multiple reviews, sometimes it can take a couple days or longer before they've accumulated enough approvals.

Diamond moderators do have the ability to approve or reject all suggested edits immediately, but we mostly prefer not to step in unless necessary since our votes are binding and every action we take risks overriding community opinion.

---

<sup>*1</sup> To be fair to those users who *do* care enough to curate but just don't know how, the "[Review Suggested Edits](https://islam.stackexchange.com/help/review-suggested-edits)" queue can be found here ([for users with at least 1000 reputation](https://islam.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/access-review-queues)):[image]

Comment: I think most of the user don't even vote. You can see the views of a question rise up but not the votes, neither negatively nor positively though some might not be privileged of voting. On the bright side there are still some people such as "medisaif" ,"The Z", "Umh" and  a few more that answer; edit or actively participate in the site.